# Binary/Hex Floating Point Entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, numbers, syntax-error

Why are decimal points only allowed in base 10? Why does the following raise a syntax error?

```
0b1011101.1101
```

Is there some ambiguity to the number I'm typing? It seems there is no possible number that string could represent other than `93.8125`

The same issue applies to other bases as well:

```
0x5d.d
```

I can program my way around this with a fairly straightforward function:

```
def base_float(number_string, base):
    n = number_string.split('.')
    number = int(n[0], base)
    if len(n) > 1 and len(n[1]):
        frac_part = float(int(n[1], base)) / base**len(n[1])
        if number < 0:
            frac_part = -frac_part
        number += frac_part
    return number
```

And it gives me the representation I expected:

```
>>> base_float('0b1011101.1101', 2)
93.8125
```

`int` accepts arbitrary base, but no decimal point, and `float` accepts a decimal point but no arbitrary base. Why?

Comment: I'd guess that no one wanted the functionality enough to get it implemented. Binary, octal, and hex tend to be more useful for integers than hex. I dunno what the actual reasons were, though.

Comment: Note that allowing fractional parts in non-decimal literals would break existing code in a few rare cases. Currently, `0b1.bit_length()` is valid code; if binary floating-point literals were introduced, `0b1.` would be a floating-point literal, and `0b1.bit_length()` would be a syntax error.

Comment: That's probably pretty significant. It's quite telling that it doesn't look for attributes on decimal numbers (i.e. `10.bit_length()` is SyntaxError rather than AttributeError)

Comment: @user2357112 These problems already arise. Compare `1..__class__` with `(1).__class__` and `1.__class__`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I'm aware of those cases. Changing the language now to allow non-decimal floating point literals might break code that was working before, though. No working code relies on `1.__class__`.

Comment: This is really a language design question, and user2357112's comment is spot on: no-one wanted or needed the functionality enough to implement it and persuade other Python devs that it was worth having in the core language.  Note that there *is* a way to convert from a hexadecimal string: try `float.fromhex('123.456')`

Comment: I think no-one wanted this feature, and they would have to change the Python grammar to make it work. It should be possible to fix the grammar to discern between `0b001.100` and `0b001.foobar()` because a function member must not start with a digit. Of course this still poses a problem for `0x110.deadbeef`, but for octal I see no actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @MarkDickinson, that's a great option I wasn't aware of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well they are called *decimal* points ;)

You could use a sort of scientific* notation

```
>>> 0b10111011101 * 0b10**-4
93.8125
>>> 0x5dd * 0x10**-1
93.8125
>>> 938125 * 10**-4 # note power is number of "decimal" places to shift
93.8125
```

* yes I realise this is not really scientific notation

**Edit**

Out of curiosity, I used the `dis` module to disassemble the byte code for a simple these statements to see if they were calculated at run-time or not

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     return 0x5dd * 0x10**-1
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               6 (93.8125)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

So it looks like you shouldn't see a performance penalty when using this method.

**Edit 2**

... Unless you use Python 2

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     return 0x5dd * 0x10**-1
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1501)
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (0.0625)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: No problem, could you elaborate on the reason why - I'm intrigued

Answer (score 1):

As people in the comments already wrote: it just wasn't considered to be needed.

They can be very useful, especially when there is a need to store the exact value of a given entity and retain it again, but these cases only rarely occur.

YOur function is - if I replace `if int_part < 0:` with `if number < 0:` - very helpful.